# Log File Size near 100% - How to find Active Transaction

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

The transaction log file size is nearing 100% on one database.
I run the below and both return 0 so no active transaction running.

The last query tells me that the database is in SIMPLE mode, but 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION' is returned in log_reuse_wait_desc column.

However, I cannot see any running transaction! I have tried querying sys.dm_tran_database_transactions but do not see any transaction for this specific database.

How do I find this transaction?

```
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT;

SELECT XACT_STATE();

SELECT name, recovery_model_desc, log_reuse_wait_desc
FROM sys.databases;
```

Comment: What is 100%? 100% of what? Did you try `DBCC OPENTRAN;` (because your first two queries only tell you about ***your own*** active transactions)? Also see [this post](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space).

Comment: 100% is from DBCC SQLPERF(LOGSPACE); So currently at 96%

Comment: DBCC OPENTRAN; returned 'No active open transactions'

Comment: Well, now it does. Could also be [deferred transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188290(v=sql.105).aspx) - have you restarted SQL Server and/or taken the database offline/online? Maybe try that and see if it clears (or you get persistent I/O errors). But I doubt that is the case...

Comment: Had not taken the database offline. But there were issues with the server querying the database. The log file just went back to 1% in past few mins

Comment: Erm..... magic?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following DMV to view any transactions that might be causing your log file to be bloated: sys.dm_tran_database_transactions.

Both your queries are limited to your current connection, meaning they give you no information about other connections made to the SQL server.

[@@Trancount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187967.aspx); 
[XACT_STATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189797.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Well if there is active transaction you have to wait for it to finish. You cannot do much. If you have multiple disks in your environment add a log file on other drive and allo wtransaction log to grow and let active transaction complete.

[Add log file to database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189253.aspx)

After the transaction finishes you can try shrinking the log file. Please dont make shrinking a habit it do causes performance issue. After shrinking you can remove the log file you added

[Remove log file from database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175574.aspx)

In some cases you can kill the transaction as well **but I would not suggest that**. I have seen in some cases where active transaction was stuck and killing it resolved the issue.

Edit: I guess if you have searched more on net you could have found more relevant articles related to what do to when log file is almost full. Develop a habit to help yourslef it will benefit you

Comment: <shudder> if you're going to recommend adding a second log file, at least add the pertinent advice to remove it once you're done.

Comment: Yes correct edited the answer

Comment: Can somebody who downvoted give reason why you did on Question which is closed and Old. Other misuse of downvote

Comment: wasn't me but people can down-vote for whatever reason they like. Age or state of the question doesn't prevent someone from finding and reading your answer, or reacting to it. Badgering people to leave a reason isn't going to have the effect you want.

Comment: I was more interested in knowing the reason so that I can improve the answer. Atleast this is why downvote is there as a medium of feedback. Personally I believe a downvote should have reason and chance be given to improve the answer. Plus my answer doesn't looks like it needs a downvote

Comment: Please review [this conversation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes). You're just never going to get the feedback of why some person didn't like your answer, sorry. There was a time I agreed with you but now I agree with most that it is just noise...

Comment: You'll also have to accept that sometimes there is a downvote without a good reason at all.

Comment: i want to down vote (but not gonna do that), and my reason is this: your provided solution is not an answer for this problem, I have same problem and I want to find the root cause of this, my next log file will get filled eventually, adding another log file may solve problem temporary but I'm here because I don't want follow this path